# I get an “Error: Cannot initialize OLE” when I try to connect to a database? C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-connection, ole

I'm trying to connect to a database via C#, but I'm getting a very unhelpful error message when I do so:

> 08:44:17: Error: Cannot initialize OLE 08:44:17: Error: Cannot initialize OLE

I've tried looking for a solution, but I've been unsuccessful. I also tried restarting my computer, which didn't help either.

I am running SQL Server 2008, and here is the relevant database code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Connects to a given database and returns the database connection.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="file">The database file name.</param>
/// <returns>The database connection.</returns>
public static SqlConnection ConnectToDb(string file)
{
    //initialize generic path
    string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    path = path.Replace("bin\\Debug\\MediaPlayer.exe", "");
    path += "Database.mdf";

    string connectionPath = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + path + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionPath);
    return connection;
}

/// <summary>
/// Executes a SQL query in a given database.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="file">The database file name.</param>
/// <param name="query">The SQL query to execute.</param>
public static void ExecuteQuery(string file, string query)
{

    SqlConnection connection = ConnectToDb(file);
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

This is database code that I have used for several project, and it has always worked before.

The error is called (I know this because I commented out other lines) on the connection.Open() line in the ExecuteQuery method.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated :).

Comment: If you are running on a 64-bit operating system, make sure you target `x86` as your platform.

Comment: Under the Build panel in the Properties page of the project, I have Active(x86) selected as the platform, if that's what you mean :).

Comment: Anyone? :( Wasted a full day on this bug, no success..

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your path does not match the location of your *Database.mdf* file.

Try to debug and see the actual value of your `path` variable and you may find that `Replace` didn't work and your `path` looks someting like *bin\Debug\MediaPlayer.exeDatabase.mdf*.

I would recommend to put the connection string into an app.config instead of finding it via Reflection.

---

*update*

It could be that the reason for this problem are insufficient privileges of the account your SQL Server is running under as described in [Deploying SQL Express database files with ClickOnce App using OLE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlexpress/thread/6146c59a-8a85-4741-8340-1defa931482f).

Try moving your database file to a different location than project debug folder.

Comment: That's not the problem, the path is fine, I triple checked before posting here. And thanks for the app.config idea, it sounds more elegant than Reflection :).

Comment: @Daniel I did a little more digging and found something concerning SQL Server OLE and UAC which seems reasonable since you stated it worked before in other projects.

Comment: Okay, the Database.mdf file is located in a folder separate from the debug folder, but when I run the program (Ctrl+F5), the Database is recreated inside the debug folder, even if I previously deleted it. I have tried moving my entire project directory to a different folder (Documents) in the hope that it'll work, but it hasn't helped.